# QComboBox show whole row of QTreeView

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want to use QtreeView to organize the data shown by a QComboBox. As you can see in my example, creating the box and setting up data works so far.
But my problem is, that the combobox itself only shows the first argument and not the whole line. what I want to have is, that there is shown the whole row, not only the first item of the row.

Is this maybe related to the fact, that each cell is selectable? Do I have to prohibit to select items at the end of the tree branch?

How can I achieve this while adding the elements to the QtreeView-data?

[image: example]
minimal example:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *


data = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['g','h','i']]

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    dispatcher = 0

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # buil UI
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        # layout
        self.box_window = QVBoxLayout()
        # content
        model = QStandardItemModel(len(data),len(data[0]))
        row = 0
        for r in data:
            col = 0
            for item in r:
                model.setData(model.index(row, col), item)
                col += 1
            row += 1
        tree_view = QTreeView()
        tree_view.setHeaderHidden(True)
        tree_view.setRootIsDecorated(False)
        tree_view.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        combobox = QComboBox()
        combobox.setMinimumSize(250,50)
        combobox.setView(tree_view)
        combobox.setModel(model)
        self.box_window.addWidget(combobox)
        self.box_window.addStretch()
        # build central widget and select it
        self.central_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
        self.centralWidget().setLayout(self.box_window)

        # show window
        self.setGeometry(50,50,1024,768)
        self.setWindowTitle("Test")
        self.show()

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Using tree views is not directly supported by QComboBox; it can be done by proper implementation, but, in any case, your model is *not* a tree, so there's no point in using such a view. While a QTableView could be used instead, but since you want to show the contents of the whole rows, there's no point in that either.

Comment: so it doesn't matter how the elements of the combobox "subview" are organized, the combobox can only show exact one item?
What about using a ListView instead of a TreeView? Is it possible to build a ListItem that looks like a table row? It is important, that the data is aligned vertically.

Comment: I'm under the impression that you're having an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Could you try to better explain what is the actual purpose of the combobox **and** the model? For instance, do you need to use the model in other views, or do you need to access the model columns individually from somewhere else? Or do you just need to **display** some data that has some kind of formatting that requires horizontal alignment in "columns"?

Comment: this combobox is intended to select one item from a set of items. Each item itself has several properties. And to choose the best fitting item, i want to list all properties (columns) of all items (rows).
Imagine, you are searching for screw. Then the combobox list will contain all screws you have. And now you want to select the right one. So you click into the box, see the list with all screws and their properties (diameter, length, head type, material, ...) and when you have found the right one and selected it, then the box shows you the properties of the selected screw.

Comment: That won't change much from [eyallesc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66241402/2001654): if you want to display the items at fixed spacing *in the combobox* (not its view) you need a much more complex implementation that completely depends on *how* you want to show them, also because QComboBox sets/updates its size based on the item contents.

Comment: an other idea was to use a table and only show one line, all others are hidden. When click into this line, the others becaome visible. But using this approach results in an other problem: [follow me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66246061/qtableview-shrink-widget-to-content)

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to concatenate the texts in the row and set as the text to be painted:

```py
class ComboBox(QComboBox):
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QStylePainter(self)
        painter.setPen(self.palette().color(QPalette.Text))
        # draw the combobox frame, focusrect and selected etc.
        opt = QStyleOptionComboBox()
        self.initStyleOption(opt)

        values = []

        for c in range(self.model().columnCount()):
            index = self.model().index(self.currentIndex(), c, self.rootModelIndex())
            values.append(index.data())
        opt.currentText = " ".join(values)
        painter.drawComplexControl(QStyle.CC_ComboBox, opt)
        # draw the icon and text
        painter.drawControl(QStyle.CE_ComboBoxLabel, opt)
```

Comment: and how to vertical align the elements? When only concatenate the elements by a space, different element length will result in a not vertical aligned list. It should look like there is a grid behind

Comment: @paul_schaefer That is really complicated because you need to calculate the size of each item and I only limit myself to giving you a simple implementation :-(