# QTableView shrink widget to content

Tags: python, pyqt5

I use a QTableView to show some data. This works so far.
There is one row and when clicking into this row, some hidden rows occure.
Click into an other row will then hide all others.
One row:
[image]

Multiple rows:

[image]

But how can i remove the white space around?
Adding `strech()` to the `QVBoxLayout` yields in a half white and a half grey window as shown in the pictutre.
[image: much white space]
`resizeRowsToContents()` also does not work. Adding spacers also have no effect.

What I want to have is, that the Window keeps the size and the white space is reduced to it's minimum (like the outer cell borders). So the cells will have a white background, the rest should be grey. Is there some kind of "strech" also inside the table view?
After expanding or collapsing the table, there should be also no white space around.

My code, which you can use:

```
import sys
import copy
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *


data = [['a','b','c','x','y'],['d','e','f','x','y'],['g','h','i','x','y']]

class TableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super(TableModel, self).__init__()
        self._data = data

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            # See below for the nested-list data structure.
            # .row() indexes into the outer list,
            # .column() indexes into the sub-list
            return self._data[index.row()][index.column()]

    def setData(self, index, value, role=Qt.EditRole):
        if role == Qt.EditRole:
            row = index.row()
            column = index.column()
            self._data[row][column] = value
            self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
            return True
        return QAbstractTableModel.setData(self, index, value, role)

    def rowCount(self, index):
        # The length of the outer list.
        return len(self._data)

    def columnCount(self, index):
        # The following takes the first sub-list, and returns
        # the length (only works if all rows are an equal length)
        return len(self._data[0])

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.selection = data[0]
        # buil UI
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        # layout
        self.box_window = QVBoxLayout()
        # content
        self.invisible_table = QTableView()
        tmp = copy.deepcopy(data)
        tmp.insert(0,self.selection)
        self.model = TableModel(tmp)
        self.invisible_table.setModel(self.model)
        self.invisible_table.setSelectionBehavior(QTableWidget.SelectRows)
        self.invisible_table.horizontalHeader().hide()
        self.invisible_table.horizontalHeader().setMinimumSectionSize(100)
        self.invisible_table.verticalHeader().hide()
        # self.invisible_table.hide()
        for i in range(1,self.model.rowCount(0)):
            self.invisible_table.setRowHidden(i,True)
        self.invisible_table.doubleClicked.connect(self.clicked)
        self.invisible_table.clicked.connect(self.clicked)
        self.invisible_table.setMinimumSize(1,1)
        self.invisible_table.resizeColumnsToContents()
        self.invisible_table.resizeRowsToContents()

        # self.box_window.addLayout(self.visible_line)
        self.box_window.addWidget(self.invisible_table)
        self.box_window.addStretch()
        # build central widget and select it
        self.central_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
        self.centralWidget().setLayout(self.box_window)

        # show window
        self.setGeometry(50,50,1024,768)
        self.setWindowTitle("Test")
        self.show()

    def popup(self, widget):
        print("popup")
        print(widget)
        self.invisible_table.show()

    def clicked(self, qmi):
        print("clicked")
        rowIndex = qmi.row()
        if rowIndex == 0:
            for i in range(1,self.model.rowCount(0)):
                if self.invisible_table.isRowHidden(i):
                    self.invisible_table.setRowHidden(i,False)
                else:
                    self.invisible_table.setRowHidden(i,True)
        else:
            self.selection = data[rowIndex-1]
            print(self.selection)
            col = 0
            for d in self.selection:
                # self.model._data[0][col]=d
                self.model.setData(self.model.index(0,col),d)
                col += 1
            for i in range(1,self.model.rowCount(0)):
                self.invisible_table.setRowHidden(i,True)

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**[EDIT]**: As requested, an edited image of what I want to achieve:
[image: result]

**[EDIT 2]**: This is, how it looks like in the moment. On the right side, there should be this "drop down list" (pseudo-combobox)
[previous approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66241051/qcombobox-show-whole-row-of-qtreeview?noredirect=1#comment117122902_66241051)
[image: current application]

Comment: you could show an image (obviously an edited image) of what you want to get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by myself.

The solution is:

- table minimum size has to be set to a value big enough, so decreasing the window will not shrink the table
- table maximum size has to be set to the smallest value, that would not crop the table

To reach both, the function `setFixedSize()` can be used. And the values (width and height) must be computed by iterating through the columns and rows and summarizing up all column widths/row heights.
Only thing to keep in mind: When there is a frame around the table, the border line thickness has to be added also.

setting the size has to be done everytime after changing the table layout (hide/show rows/columns, add/remove rows/columns, add/hide header and so on)

```
# determine width and height
table_width = 0
table_height = 0
for i in range(table.columnCount()):
    table_width += table.columnWidth(i)
for i in range(table.rowCount()):
    table_height += table.rowHeight(i)
if not table.horizontalHeader().isHidden():
    table_height += table.horizontalHeader().height()
table.verticalHeader().hide()
table.setFrameStyle(QFrame.NoFrame)
table.setFixedSize(table_width,table_height)
```

result:
[image: result]